# Assisting with COM; selecting 2 variable cellranges in excel

Tags: com, autohotkey

im having some trouble selecting some variable cellranges in excel with ahk

i tried:

NR = 10

X0.Range("A"NR:"B"NR).select

but this isnt working

can anybody tell me the right solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. at a glance, it looks like you are not linking your variables and strings right.  You have to use a `.` (space dot space) to join strings and variables in the mode you are using.

```
X0.Range("A"NR:"B"NR).select
```

I'm not sure how COM works with Excel, but what about this:

```
XO.Range("A" . NR . ":B" . NR). select
```

Or this:

```
thisrange = A%NR%:B%NR%
XO.Range(thisrange).select
```